# How do you communicate with a Necron Warrior?

Tags: warhammer-40k, necrons

The average Necron warrior is not the best at pleasant communication.

[image]

I don't expect him to chat to his mates down the pub. I wouldn't be surprised if the Necron lords (looking at 6th edition fluff) recited poetry.

How do the the two communicate? Wireless? Speech? Sub-ether radio?

Comment: They communicate via interpretative dance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Having an empire which has spanned more than 60 million years, and the length and breadth of the galaxy itself, it would not be unreasonable to believe The Necron may use a variety of electromagnetic and para-psychic communication means both sublight and faster-than-light at one point or another to communicate and maintain their empire. An empire is only as effective as the speed of communication and response across that empire.**

Before the 6th Edition revisions, communication between the Necrons needed to be considered in the context of their physiology. There are, in effect, two classes of Necron. The lowly warrior consigned to the battlefield, dying repeatedly and losing their independence and autonomy and the Necron noble who has managed to maintain a sophisticated psychology, a position of power and leadership and has others able and willing to die on their behalf.

> Necron society, such as it is, is hierarchical. The highest of the Necrons are the Phaerons, the ruler of entire dynasties which comprise many worlds. Beneath these are the Overlords, who rule clusters of Tomb Worlds within their Phaeron's domain. Beneath the Overlords are the Lords, each overseeing a Tomb World. Phaerons and Overlords are served by a Royal Court of Necron Lords and Crypteks. The size of a Royal Court is not only prestigious, it is also an indication of that military power of the noble who rules it. **--Codex: Necrons, 5th edition**

- A Necron warrior does not have a living body. Their body is comprised of "living metal" a nano-technological robotic construct capable of repairing itself from almost any injury except complete obliteration.
- Necrons neither eat nor sleep, nor ever need to. They can, however for centuries at a time, enter a hibernation which does not impair their function, no matter how long it lasts, as long as their technology is active. Their psychology is a construct linked to technological array which in the event of their body's destruction, is immediately transmitted back to a reconstruction tomb where they await repair or the forging of a completely new body.
- It is the relay of the mind from body to tomb to new body, particularly if the body is considerably damaged, which causes the slow, inexorable loss of mental quality reducing many of the lesser soldiers to little more than mindless drones, functioning as nigh-indestructible shock troops and used as cannon fodder by the [Necron Lords](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Necron_Lord#.UGKAwY1lT8Y).
- Since the Necron can, relatively instantly, move the entirety of their consciousness across the battlefield using their communications technology, it make sense, this same technology is used by Necron Lords to control units who have lost true sentience or to direct units still capable of independent action.
- Necrons have little use for oratorical speech or leadership using morale, but considering their origins as organic beings, they may choose to retain technology for communicating with the living if it suits their purposes to do so. It is certain among the Necron Lords, such communication still deals with the accumulation of power and status in their hierarchical social structures. Negotiations between Necron Lords and [Crypteks](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Cryptek#.UGJ9Ro1lT8Y) for example, are likely as sophisticated, layered and nuanced as any communication between two near immortal beings can be.
- Electromagnetic manipulations of another species communication equipment should be well within their ability to perform, and given their species longevity and vast resources available to them, communication with most races is at least possible, if for no other reason than to instill terror in those unable to resist them.
- Being a race with an empire that spans the entire galaxy, it is likely part of their technology allows them to communicate in near-real time across the vastness of space. No other modern species, has the breadth of technological sophistication, nor the longevity in using it, the Necron have had access to. For enemies such as the Eldar, Orks or Adeptus Astartes, the Necron rarely speak. Their railguns and formidable Pylons are the only communication they need.

Answer (score 4):

Answering the question in the title, as seen in Dawn of War: Dark Crusade, the Necrons can turn humans into mouthpieces for the Necrons. They use these mouthpieces to inspire fear in their enemies, facilitating their slaughter. It stands to reason that they have access to the same technology for their Lords and other relevant individuals.

Comment: That [human](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Tomas_Macabee) was a blank, I think the fluff states that necrons don't kill the blanks, but instead turn them into fellow necrons.